# Wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ with range $-\frac{x}{2}<t$ and "initial conditions" at $u(x,-\frac{x}{2})$ and $u_x(x,-\frac{x}{2})$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ with range $-\frac{x}{2}<t$ and $-\infty<x<\infty$. "initial conditions":
\begin{align}
u\big(x,-\frac{x}{2}\big) &=
\begin{cases}
1, & |x|<1,  \\
0, &  \text{else}.
\end{cases} \\
u_x\big(x,-\frac{x}{2}\big) &=0
\end{align}

find $$\int_{\frac{3}{2}}^\infty u(x,0)\, \mathrm{d}x$$

I struggle to understand how to use the range $-\frac{x}{2}<t$ and the fact the that the "initial condition" are at $t=-\frac{x}{2}$.